# How to use CoreData Objects temporarily without needing to insert them into a Context?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui, nsmanagedobject

**Context**

I am working on a feature, that allows users to add `Components` to `CoreData`. Those `Components` are obviously `NSManagedObjects` inserted and saved into a `Context`.
In addition, I also want to give the user a variety of predefined `Components`. However, I do not like the idea of populating those predefined ones into `CoreData` at the first `App Launch`, since this is really prone to bugs, especially when utilising `CloudKit`. So my idea was to generate a `List` of predefined `NSManagedObjects` without inserting them into a `Context`, which would make them temporarily, but they could be used in the same way as the real ones. However, as far as I understand, creating `NSManagedObjects` without a `Context` isn't really working.

---

**Code**

```swift
let predefinedComponents: [Component] {
    var components: [Component] = []

    for name in names {
        let component = Component() // This was my idea of creating a temporary NSManagedObject without inserting it into a Context.
        component.name = name

        components.append(component)
    }

    return components
}

struct ComponentsView: View {
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.name)]) private var components: FetchedResults<Component>

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(allComponents) { component in 
            ComponentRow(component: component)
        }
    }

    private var allComponents: [Component] {
        var allComponents: [Component] = predefinedComponents

        for component in components {
            allComponents.append(component)
        }

        return allComponents
    }
}

struct ComponentRow: View {
    @ObservedObject var component: Component

    var body: some View {
        Text(component.name)
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

How can I achieve my goal described above while being able to work with predefined `Components` without having to populate them into `CoreData` at the first `AppLaunch`?

Comment: You can’t there is no real point but you could use a protocol to make similar objects.

Comment: What are those predefined components, some kind of blueprints or something that the user can edit directly? Either way, have you considered making them a separate type that can be converted to a Component?

Comment: *creating NSManagedObjects without a Context isn't really working*. That’s right but you can use a child context which you can either throw away or merge the records you want to keep into the main context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create "free floating" managed objects that don't belong to a context but you need to provide the entity description to do it-- so you would use `Component(entity:insertInto:)`. The first argument is the `NSEntityDescription` for `Component`. The second one is a context, but it's an optional, so you can make it nil. If you wanted to add it to a context later, use `NSManagedObjectContext.insert()`.

It might be better to use an in-memory persistent store instead of a SQLite store. Then you would have a context that only existed while the app was running but did not save to a file. You can set one of those up with `NSPersistentContainer` if you change the persistent store description.

I can't tell from your question which of these would be better for you.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest and most elegant way is to create a "throwaway scratchpad" context just for the pre-defined Components.

This scratchpad context will be a child of the viewContext, or any background context depending on your use case.

This is how you create the scratchpad:

```
let scratchpadContext = NSManagedObjectContext(.mainQueue)
scratchpadContext.parent = dataProvider.container.viewContext
```

The example above creates a context for the main queue, which I assume is your case based on your question. But if you need to access it from a background thread, you initialise it with .privateQueue.

So, as long as you don't save the scratchpadContext, your temporary pre-defined Components will never be saved on your Persistent store. And when it's de-initialised, any NSManagedObject that you've created with it will be thrown away.